# Soundcloud-style commenting on MP3 files in Drupal?

Tags: php, drupal, mp3, soundcloud

Is there a way to comment on MP3 files the way they do on Soundcloud? I.e. Users can pick a point in time on the streaming mp3, and leave a comment at a specific point.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Everything is possible. Hey, Soundcloud done it too! What's your question?

Comment: Is there a component or something I can use to do this, or must I code it myself?

Comment: .. use soundcloud .. / or do it yourself for the community ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a misunderstanding. First, you will need some kind of streaming player, probably flash based. Now, it is up to you to pull comments from the database and visualise the way you want in your streaming player.